# A Good Book for Solid Material properties

Tags: solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, material-science, stress-strain

I want to know a book which provides all solid material properties: Linear/Non-Linear Stress-Strain Data, Thermo-Elastic data (with specific heat function of temperature)... I will need them for Structural dynamic purpose

Comment: ASM International databases and references? ASME handbooks?

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks for your reference. Do you know if there is a book where there would be constitutive Model (Stress-Strain relation formula) for each Material?